# Invalid column name when updating column with CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I want to populate a column 'surplus' with the difference between the amount  submitted by bidders and the winning bid.

```
ALTER TABLE bids
ADD surplus FLOAT NULL;
GO

WITH cteSurplus AS 
(
    SELECT 
        projectId, 
        bidAmount, bidderRank, 
        surp = (bidAmount-MIN(bidAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY projectId))
    FROM 
        bids
    GROUP BY 
        projectId, bidAmount, bidderRank
)
UPDATE cteSurplus 
SET surplus = surp 
FROM cteSurplus;
GO
```

When I run this query, I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'shortage'

For reference, I previously had to populate my rank column, and this query ran without any errors:

```
ALTER TABLE bids
ADD bidderRank INT NULL;
GO

WITH cteRank AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        r = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY projectId ORDER BY winningResultBool DESC, bidAmount DESC)   
    FROM bids
)
UPDATE cteRank 
SET bidderRank = r 
FROM cteRank ;
GO
```

Does the error come from the subtraction and/or the use of `MIN` in `bidAmount-MIN(bidAmount)`?

Comment: Your CTE, in the first statement, has no column `surplus` hence the error when you try to run the `UPDATE`. The column `shortage` isn't even in your statement, so I have no idea where that is coming from, but it is *not* that statement.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because my second CTE statement doesn't have a bidderRank column either, yet it works.

Comment: Yes it does, it has `SELECT *`, and `bidderRank` is a column in your table `bids`.

Comment: You're right. I added the `shortage` column to my select and to the group by, and now I get this error: `Cannot update the view or function 'cteSurplus' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.`

Comment: Well yes, you have a `GROUP BY` in the query within the CTE... The error is **literally** telling you the problem. *Why* do you have a `GROUP BY` in the query anyway?

Comment: Ah, I thought since `MIN` is an aggregate, I needed to group it. The update works now, thanks.

Comment: `MIN` is an aggregate, but you have it as a windowed aggregate, so there is no need for the `GROUP BY`; so the dataset itself is not being aggregated. Windowed aggregates *are* allowed in updatable views/CTEs/etc.

Comment: It makes sense now that you say it. Thanks again